# Custom noscript style fails AMP validation, confusing it with boilerplate

Tags: amp-html

I have an opacity animation on my AMP HTML page on a couple of elements. I have styled these elements to have `opacity: 0` so I can fade them in.

In case the user has javascript disabled and the elements can't be faded in, I want them to have `opacity: 1`.

I've tried using this HTML in my `<head>` to achieve it:

```
<style amp-custom>      
   .bubble-animated {
    opacity: 0;
  }
</style>
<noscript>
  <style amp-custom>
    .bubble-animated {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  </style>
</noscript>
```

However, I'm getting the following two errors from the AMP validator:

- The attribute 'amp-custom' may not appear in tag 'noscript > style[amp-boilerplate] - old variant'. (on the second `<style amp-custom>` tag)
- The tag 'noscript enclosure for boilerplate' appears more than once in the document. (on the actual boilerplate `<noscript>` tag)

I've tried a few variations of this, but I couldn't get my page to validate. A full HTML page of my site is available here: https://pastebin.com/uAMCcQur

What is the correct way to achieve this? Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the attributes on the `html` tag to check whether the JS of the AMP lib has loaded on the page.

The html tag may look like this:

```
<html ⚡="" lang="de" amp-version="1531347091169" class="i-amphtml-singledoc i-amphtml-standalone" style="padding-top: 0px !important;">
```

The attribute `amp-version` can be used to check this in your css like this:

```
<style amp-custom>      
  html[amp-version] .bubble-animated {
    opacity: 0;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: The concept works perfectly, except it needs to be only one rule like so
`html[amp-version] .bubble-animated { opacity: 0; }`

Comment: Thanks. Edited it

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
  footer {
    margin-top: 3rem;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
</style><noscript>
  <style amp-custom>
    .bubble-animated {
      opacity: 1;
    }
  </style>
</noscript>
```

to

```
  footer {
    margin-top: 3rem;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }

   .bubble-animated {
      opacity: 1;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this will help me, since I don't want the opacity to be 1 if the browser has javascript enabled. That's why I'm using the noscript tag. I specifically want those elements to be invisible when the site loads, so I can fade them in using an animation.

Comment: what do you mean `javascript enabled`? The only enabled javascript is amp libraries. and if amp libraries are not enabled, then the page will be distorted.

Comment: I want my site to display correctly in browsers that have javascript generally disabled. Since my site is quite simple, it does not require the AMP libraries to display correctly. Using Marcus' answer, I managed to make it work.

Comment: got it - i misinterpreted the question